# Image zooming with horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, zooming

I want to implement a Zoom feature in an image view and also want to put a horizontal scroll view.

Suppose I have a large image.  If I touch this image, it should zoom and also be scrollable horizontally.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about a particular problem you are having trying to do this? I recommend checking out the FAQ entry, [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebView. see here: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/18/using-webview-as-a-image-zoom-view-control/

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want use web view then you can use touch event please visit this .

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847